# Convert PHP 8.1 Enums to constants

Tags: php, laravel, php-8.1

I have this PHP 8.1 Enum Class but when I uploaded my code, my VPS supports up to PHP 8.0.

```
 enum AssignmentState: string
 {
    case Draft = 'draft';
    case Published = 'published';
    case Graded = 'graded';
 }
```

And this is how I use it in the controller and Model Respectively

```
$request->has('status') ? ($status = $request->status) : ($status = AssignmentState::Published->value);
```

```
protected $casts = [
    'status' => AssignmentState::class,
];
```

So how do I backport enums such that they work with PHP 8.0

Comment: What's your goal here? Rewriting your code to just be PHP 8, or "PHP 8 for only as long as your host hasn't bumped PHP to 8.1 yet"? If the first, just rewrite your AssignmentState as a class with `final public const` values and reference those. If the latter, you probably want to define a namespace with a set of instances of a simple object type with a `value` property so that the code in your controller stays the same.

Comment: The goal is to rewrite my code to PHP 8.0 because it's what the server supports.  I've just recently started using Laravel, I don't have a strong foundation in PHP. How can I rewrite them using `final public const`? An example would be a lifesaver. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want PHP 8.0 code without enums or code based on enums, you can use a class with const properties:

```php
 class AssignmentState
 {
    public const Draft = 'draft';
    public const Published = 'published';
    public const Graded = 'graded';
 }
 
 echo AssignmentState::Published;
```

And then you'll have to remove the `->value` bits from the code that relies on this, since you're not working with enums anymore but just plain strings.

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
abstract class AssignmentState
{
    const DRAFT = 'draft';
    const PUBLISHED = 'published';
    const GRADED = 'graded';
}
```

in Model

```
$request->has('status') ? ($status = $request->status) : ($status = AssignmentState::PUBLISHED);
```

I think, you shouldn't cast status